# Create a brodcast botframework - SDK NodeJS

Tags: node.js, botframework

Can I send a message to all the users who spoke with the bot? It would be a message and it would be for all users. (Broadcast)?

botbuilder 3.14.0 - nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) for that as it allows you to send the user a message that is not directly related to the current topic of conversation.

Here's a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages/simpleSendMessage/index.js) on how to send an ad-hoc proactive message:

```
'use strict';

var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
  console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// setup bot credentials
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
  appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
  appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

// Bot Storage: Here we register the state storage for your bot. 
// Default store: volatile in-memory store - Only for prototyping!
// We provide adapters for Azure Table, CosmosDb, SQL Azure, or you can implement your own!
// For samples and documentation, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure
var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector).set('storage', inMemoryStorage); // Register in memory storage

// send simple notification
function sendProactiveMessage(address) {
  var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
  msg.text('Hello, this is a notification');
  msg.textLocale('en-US');
  bot.send(msg);
}

var savedAddress;
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

// Do GET this endpoint to delivey a notification
server.get('/api/CustomWebApi', (req, res, next) => {
    sendProactiveMessage(savedAddress);
    res.send('triggered');
    next();
  }
);

// root dialog
bot.dialog('/', function(session, args) {

  savedAddress = session.message.address;

  var message = 'Hello! In a few seconds I\'ll send you a message proactively to demonstrate how bots can initiate messages.';
  session.send(message);

  message = 'You can also make me send a message by accessing: ';
  message += 'http://localhost:' + server.address().port + '/api/CustomWebApi';
  session.send(message);

  setTimeout(() => {
   sendProactiveMessage(savedAddress);
  }, 5000);
});
```

You can also find a complete sample that shows how to send proactive messages using the Bot Builder SDK for Node.js [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages)

Comment: Thanks @Ali Heikal

Comment: var savedAddress; 
What would you have in that variable?  
Would you have the user ID on facebook?

Comment: You're welcome, this variable is essentially used to store the session address.

Comment: Another question: Can these proactive messages be sent from the bot to multiple users or can it only be sent from the bot to one user at a time?

Comment: Yes, your messages can be sent to multiple users at a time, using a loop for example.